# Rails javascript_include_tag somehow pulling in all files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my layout view

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.10.1.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

why am I getting all of these when the page renders?

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/LZA/LZA.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/LZA/MapKit.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/LZA/Torch.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/LZA/cordova-2.6.0.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/LZA/jquery-1.10.1.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/LZA/jquery-1.9.1.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/LZA/jquery.form.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/LZA/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/apps.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/simulator.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/webservice.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All I did was add some `.css` and `.js` files to the folders so I can use them elsewhere in the site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `application.js` file (or any of the others included), you should see something like

```
//= require home
//= require simulator
//= require webservice
```

That's pulling the files named `home.js`, `simulator.js` and `webservice.js`, and adding them to your site.

Take a look at the [Rails Assets Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: 2nd answer for me in less than an hour. You're on a roll. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I tried and it said I had to wait another 7 minutes... then I got distracted.